# What was life like for the average Coruscanti, during the Galactic Empire?

Tags: star-wars

What was the general quality of life on Coruscant for the common citizen, during the days of the Galactic Empire?

In particular,  were conditions worse on Coruscant than somewhere like Tatooine?

Comment: This seems very open-ended... I don't really think this is an appropriate question for SE.

Comment: Please add some more specific aspects of life on Coruscant that you're curious about. Discussing "what life was like" is awfully broad.

Comment: This is a repeat of a [previous question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/134303/513790), now deleted. Please narrow it down, or it too will probably be closed as "Too Broad" again.

Comment: I think "too broad" depends on what is actually out there in canon. For example, even if you got more specific and asked something like "what kind of work did people on the lower levels of Coruscant do", it could be too broad if the canon mentions a huge number of different jobs done by people on the lower levels, but fine if only a few have been mentioned. In this case, I think there is very little actual info in canon about life for Coruscanti during the Empire, so I think the question is fine.

Comment: Do you wanna buy some death sticks?

Comment: What  constitutes a "common citizen?"

Comment: I edited your question to focus more narrowly on what you seem to be asking. Feel free to revert if the intended meaning was lost.

Comment: Thanks for editing Adamant! That can help with the answering!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the new "[Tarkin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))" novel, there's a pretty good description of Coruscant during the period of Empire. Basically it's pretty nice and the average Coruscanti citizen seems reasonably happy with their lot in life. There are mentions of work being readily available (especially in construction) and a good range of facilities, sporting events, cultural activities and general entertainments.

Certainly the lowest levels and industrial areas were heavily crime-ridden and gang-controlled (something that Palpatine had secretly allowed during the Clone Wars) but this was being brought under control by Vader and his underworld contacts and for the most part, it was non-humans (living in ghettos) that populated the lowest levels rather than human communities.

> *He had heard that one needn’t have been absent from Coruscant for years to be startled by the changes, in that each day saw buildings raised, demolished, incorporated into ever larger and taller monstrosities, or merely stripped of Republic-era ornamentation and renovated in accordance with a more severe aesthetic. Curved lines were yielding to harsh angles; sophistication to declaration. Fashions had changed along similar lines, with few outside the Imperial court affecting cloaks, headcloths, or garish robes. **By most accounts, though, Coruscanti were satisfied, especially those who lived and worked in the upper tiers of the fathomless cityscape; content if for no other reason than to have the brutal war behind them.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Tarkin: A Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tarkin_(novel))</sup></sub>

We (the viewer) don't spend a lot of time at ground level for obvious reasons, but by all accounts the standard of living for the *average* Coruscanti is vastly above that of the average Tatooinian. For those that are below the average (which primarily includes non-humans), things are admittedly pretty shitty. The air is polluted near the ground and crime is endemic.

> *Wealthy citizens in the city's upper levels breathe rich, filtered air. Undercity dwellers, however, are forced to inhale the toxic fumes from millennia of vehicle and factory waste*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)</sup></sub>

The new (canon) comic [Obi-Wan and Anakin #2](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/57731/obi-wan_and_anakin_2016_2) gives us a glimpse into the *actual living conditions* of those who live in the "sub-surface" areas of the planet. As you can see, it's dusty, dirty, dark and decidedly unpleasant, albeit not without its crude charms.

[image]

Comment: Why the heck are people downvoting this?

Comment: @Null - The original question was a bit open-ended (and indeed a dupe of a closed question). It certainly didn't deserve closing, but I can see why some might have felt that way. My answer seems to have gotten caught in the crossfire.

Comment: The original post was too broad, in my view, because it asked "what life was like" on Coruscant, when (like any planet-sized city) there was a broad spectrum of classes,  living in conditions that varied from from sub-Tatooine poverty to unimaginable luxury and power. Narrowing it to ask about the *average* or *common* resident makes it meaningful, though, just as one could meaningfully ask about the *average* quality of life in Japan relative to Colombia. I declined to VTC and upvoted accordingly. Not that your answer was downvote-worthy in any case.

Comment: @Null - lack hand-drawn circles?